# Python encode piano notes in 88 bits - int too large to convert to C long

Tags: python, neural-network

The piano keyboard has 88 keys:
[image]

I would like to encode one note or one chord in 88 bit array. I do this, for example:
`A4` is `0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001000000000000000000000000000000`

Next I convert this number to decimal. When I have chord the final number is really big. The problem is when I put this big number into array from NumPy I gets:

```
note_data = np.array(note_data, dtype=np.int64)
OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long
```

My point is to feed recurrent neural netowrk this kind of data or maybe is better representation on music notes into numbers?

EDIT:

Another example of encode `C3` note:

`C3 = np.array([0000000000000000000000000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000], dtype=int)`

and error sitll the same:

```
OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long
```

It's possible to reduce this error?

Answer (score 3):

That seems like a bad way to encode the information. A C chord and a C7 chord would be very different numbers even though they are similar conceptually.

I would take your idea, but instead of smashing the information into a single int, make your input a binary vector of length 88 created in the way you describe. In this way, a C and C7 will have similar inputs, differing in only one location of the vector.

As a simplified one octave example going from C to B:

```
C : [1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0]
C7: [1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0]
```

This kind of encoding is making use of “dummy variables”. It is like the “Bag of Words” encoding used a lot in Natural Language Processing.

Comment: Ok, Thank you for reply. I known One hot encoding method. But in which way can I encode chord like `C, E, G` on one hot encoding method?

Comment: binary vector of length 88 is not too long as I desctibed? Yes, C and C7 is similar but C7 have more information it also have E and G.

Comment: No, a vector of length 88 should be no problem at all.

Comment: I made an example in one octave.

Comment: ok I got your point I did this before asking on datascience. If we have 88 binary vector representing single chord. C chord and C7 would be very diffrent numbers. If we have input vector of length 12 C is 2192 and C7 2194 its close. How about octaves? I decide to test with 88 input because I can place chord in diffrent octaves. Now I known it's bad idea. In which way can I represent octave? As concatenation 12 bits for notes and 8 bits of octave?

Comment: I’m not sure what your question is. Just do the full 88 in this way. It sounds like you already did this in which case I encourage you to follow your initial instincts, they were good! Creating ints out of binary just means that you are forcing your model to learn how to decompose the ints back into binary *on top of* an already difficult task. The point of input encoding is to make life *easier* for the model, not harder.

Comment: Also consider an E Minor chord vs C7. Very similar chords, and they are similar in the binary encoding one octave example, but differ by a large amount as ints

Comment: I'm sorry I had to misunderstand you. In the my question I try to encode single chord on note into 88 bits. In the answer you say it is bad way. I try to encode one note or chord into 88 bits but I have a problem with numpy when I encode this into decimal as I described `OverflowError` for some chords.

Comment: I got your point... not single int but vector as you say